# Getting members of an object, during runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, controls

I have a situation, don't know if my approach is right or not please guide me through this.
Suppose I have a Panel control containing numerous controls in it,
During runtime I performed an iteration over each control in that panel by using
`Panel1.Controls` property,
Now in those controls they could be anything `TextBox`, `Button`, `DropDown` etc.
Now I want to find during runtime, which Controls is of which type and after that find if any specific property is contained in that control or not & if that property exists there than set the value of that property.
I think I would have to do some thing using `Reflection` here but don't know from where to start.

sample code:

```
 foreach (Control cntrl in Panel1.Controls)
        { 
            //find type of the control
            // find any specific property's existence in that control
            // if property exists than set value of that property
        }
```

Any other more relevant approach is welcomed too, for performing this task in runtime.

Sorry I forgot to mention
I don't want to use `is` keyword here because controls are of may types, and I want to create a global function which can be used for any panel with out knowing the types of controls present in that panel.

Thankx in advance.

Comment: Can you give more specific details about which properties you want to know about, and whether you *know* which properties you're interested in beforehand? You may well *not* need reflection.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that last part? What exactly do you mean, why dont you want to use `is`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using reflection you can achieve this.

`Get the metadata for the property`, and then set it. This will allow you to **check for the existence of the property**, and verify that it can be set:

```
foreach (Control cntrl in Panel1.Controls)
{ 
   PropertyInfo prop = cntrl.GetType().GetProperty("Name", BindingFlags.Public |            BindingFlags.Instance);
   if(null != prop && prop.CanWrite)
   {
       prop.SetValue(cntrl, "MyName", null);
   }
}
```

Or try this if you do not want to use reflection

```
foreach (Control cntrl in Panel1.Controls)
            { 
                if(cntrl is TextBox)
                {
                  TextBox txt = (TextBox)ctrl;
                  txt.Text = "Your value here";
                  // your textbox code here
                }
                else if(cntrl is DropDown)
                {
                  // your DropDown code here
                }
                if(cntrl is Button)
                {
                  // your Button code here
                }
            }
```

*Note:*  **is** keyword Checks if an object is compatible with a given type. For example, the following code can determine if an object is an instance of the MyObject type, or a type that derives from MyObject:

Comment: plz review my question I have just edited it, I don't want to use `is` keyword

Comment: Yeah that one with Reflection is right for me, thanx. But I have posted something like that too but my one is more verbose, yours look slimmer :)

Answer (score 0):

The [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) keyword is what you are looking for.

```
foreach(Control ctrl in Panel1.Controls)
{
 if(ctrl is TextBox) //Is the control of type TextBox?
 {
   (TextBox)ctrl.Text = "TextBox Test!"; //Cast it to a TextBox
 } else if(ctrl is Button) //Is the control of type Button?
 {
   (Button)ctrl.Text = "Button Test!";
 }
}
```

There are 2 ways of casting from type A to B;

```
(TextBox)ctrl
```

or

```
ctrl as TextBox;
```

The difference is that the first approach throws an exception if the cast fails, the second returns null. In your case you are fairly sure its the correct type, so it doesnt matter much which you use.

Comment: This is probably a slightly confusing example, because `.Text` is a property of `Control`...

Comment: It is rather visual, and it shows how to fork code depending on the type of the object. There arent many button or textbox specific properties that are so visual.

Comment: Using `is` then `as` is very strange. Either use `as` and then a check for null, or `is` then a cast.

Comment: plz review my question I have just edited it, I don't want to use `is `keyword

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you explain why you prefer the one above the other? Functionally it would be the same, and i actually prefer using `as` aesthetically because it creates a more unified look. Using `as` looks similar to using `is` and thus looks cleaner, eventhough the cast wont end up being null. (I did edit my answer, just because you are probably right.)

Comment: @TJHeuvel: I use `as` when it's still *valid* for it not to be the right type, and cast when it would definitely indicate a programming error. In this case, you're certain that it's the right type - the only reason `as` would return `null` would be if you'd had a copy/paste error, in which case it would be better to get a casting exception than a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OfType` extension:

```
List<TextBox> textBoxes = myPanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
string allText = string.Join("\n", textBoxes.ConvertAll(t => t.Text));
```

The above example will find all TextBox controls in the panel then read their text into a  single string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Type.GetProperties method like this, from MSDN:

```
public class TypeMain
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        Type myType =(typeof(MyTypeClass));
        // Get the public properties.
        PropertyInfo[] myPropertyInfo = myType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance);
        Console.WriteLine("The mumber of public properties is {0}.", myPropertyInfo.Length);
        // Display the public properties.
        DisplayPropertyInfo(myPropertyInfo);
        // Get the nonpublic properties.
        PropertyInfo[] myPropertyInfo1 = myType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance);
        Console.WriteLine("The number of protected properties is {0}.", myPropertyInfo1.Length);
        // Display all the nonpublic properties.
        DisplayPropertyInfo(myPropertyInfo1);       
    }
    public static void DisplayPropertyInfo(PropertyInfo[] myPropertyInfo)
    {
        // Display information for all properties.
        for(int i=0;i<myPropertyInfo.Length;i++)
        {
            PropertyInfo myPropInfo = (PropertyInfo)myPropertyInfo[i];
            Console.WriteLine("The property name is {0}.", myPropInfo.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("The property type is {0}.", myPropInfo.PropertyType);
        }
    }
```

The PropetyInfo class also have helpful properties like CanRead, CanWrite. Check out MSDN page of [PropertyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this myself, please review it, and tell me if it is right from the performance point of view.

```
 foreach (Control cntrl in Panel1.Controls)
        {
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] props = cntrl.GetType().GetProperties();
            IEnumerable<System.Reflection.PropertyInfo> searchedProp = props.Where(delegate(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo p)
                                                                        {
                                                                            return p.Name.Contains("YourPropertyName");
                                                                        });
            if (searchedProp != null && searchedProp.Count() > 0)
                searchedProp.First().SetValue(cntrl, true, null); // Here true should be replaced by the value that is allowed by the property you are setting at runtime
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

for each of the controls, get the control type den the name of the type.
Get value of the control thru reflection, if its ur desired value
do the set value operation on the desired property.

```
foreach (Control control in panel1.Controls)
                {

                    Type controlType = control.GetType();
                    switch (controlType.Name)
                    {
                        case "CheckBox":
                            if ((bool)controlType.GetProperty("Checked").GetValue(control,null))
                                controlType.GetProperty("Name").SetValue(control,"Check1",null);                        
                            break;
                        case "TextBox":
                          //TODO
                            break;
                        case "ComboBox":
                           //TODO
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try as follows,

```
using System.Reflection;  // reflection namespace
 // get all public static properties of MyClass type
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;

 foreach (Control cntrl in Panel1.Controls)
{


if( cntrl is TextBox)
{

propertyInfos = typeof(TextBox).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                              BindingFlags.Static);
//Loop thru property info n find the name using PropertyInfo.Name
 if(property.Name == "property name")
  //assign values
}
else 
{ 
    //others
}


}
```